# Third eigenvector from two non-orthogonal eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A$:

$
  A= \frac{1}{2}
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   -1 & 1 & -1 \\
   2 & -2 & 0 \\
   1 & -1 & -1
  \end{array} } \right]
$

The matrix has three eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 0$, and $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = -1$, which means that there's one duplicate eigenvalue. Solving for the eigenvectors yields $v_1 = [ 1\ 1\ 0 ]^T$ and $v_2 = [ 0\ 1\ 1 ]^T$. The problem I have is that I need a third eigenvector. I know that for orthogonal eigenvectors $v_3 = v_1\times v_2$, but $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not orthogonal to each other in this case. I have no idea how I'm supposed to find $v_3$ in this here. I've tried to look online and through some literature I have, but to no avail. Does anyone know how to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: corrected my matrix. middle row, middle column needed a minus sign

Comment: For the matrix $A$ as given above, I get characteristic equation $- \lambda^3 + \lambda +1 = 0,$ which means your eigenvalues may be incorrect.

Comment: $Av_1$ is not a multiple of $v_1$

Comment: Like Elliot says, you have the incorrect eigenvalues (related: $v_1$ is not an eigenvector). Moreover, the premise of your question is false: you are labouring under the delusion that all $n\times n$ matrices should have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, which needs not be the case.

Comment: I believe the middle entry in your matrix should be $-2$ instead of $2$?

Comment: Whoops. Yes, I made a mistake in the matrix. The middle entry should have been $-2$. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda=-1$ is a double root of the characteristic polynomial but there exists only one eigenvector to this root. A more formal way to say this is: the eigenvalue $-1$ has algebraic multiplicity of $2$ but geometric multiplicity of $1$.

You cannot diagonalize the matrix to $A=UDU^{-1}$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues and $U$ is the orthogonal matrix of the eigenvectors.
But you can write it in [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)
$$A = QJQ^{-1}$$
where $Q=[v_1 v_2 v_3]$ and
$J=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$.

$v_3$ is a [generalized eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) that satisfies $(A-\lambda_3I)v_3=v_2$, that is $v_3=[1,-1,0]^T$.

Answer (score 1):

An $n\times n$ matrix doesn't have to have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. But, if what you want is just an orthogonal direction to $v_1$ and $v_2$, then you can apply [Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Book%3A_Linear_Algebra_(Schilling_Nachtergaele_and_Lankham)/09%3A_Inner_product_spaces/9.05%3A_The_Gram-Schmidt_Orthogonalization_procedure) which in your case gives the vector
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}- \frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}\\1\end{array}\right]$$
Hope that helps.